Could the masses of the fermions come from renormalization effects?
Renormalization makes it so that the couplings in a theory change with the energy scale. Could the masses of the all the different fundamental fermions be explained by running of the Yukawa couplings between the fermions and the Higgs field, where the complicated scheme we observe is the result of something simpler at higher energy? E.g., could it be the case that only the top quark has a non-zero Yukawa coupling with the Higgs field at high energy, and the rest of the couplings "leak" out from renormalization effects resulting from that interaction?

It’s certainly possible, and there have been hundreds or perhaps even thousands of papers written on this exact subject. For a few references, see the start of this paper.

As always with flavor, the problem is that there are a lot of strong constraints and no hard evidence for any of the models proposed. And they’re all similarly clunky, so there isn’t an undisputed favored model. It is unlikely for this situation to change much in the next 20 years.
